# Where to start debugging app built with iOS 5 that runs on 6 but not 5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have an app that needs to support 5.1 devices.

It runs fine on an iOS 5 iPhone, but not an iPad.  On iPad with iOS 5.1.1 it just hangs.  I am not sure how to go about debugging it.  I have commented out everything in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but after the end, I just hangs.  If I pause the app it stops at `mach_msg_trap`, which is not much help... at least to me.

If I run the same app on the iPad 6.0 simulator, it works fine.  I have built the app with the 5.1 SDK and have tried it in all simulators.

Any help on where to start would be appreciated.  I am not even what sure what details to give for help.

Comment: I think this is a bug...have the same problem

Comment: well others must have had this issue as well, there must be a fix to the issue.  Plenty of apps are built for the iPhone and IOS 5.1 and they do run on the iPad.  I have written some myself.  This problem just puzzles me.  If you fins a solution I would love to hear it.

Comment: Try to create empty/sample project and see if it hangs. Check if there are any compiler/linker warnings. Connect iPad and trace didFinishLaunching. When it hanged, try to pause the app and see where it is hanging.